# operator overloading using template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-function

I'm writing a class named **Double** which extends the built in type 'double' in c++. It has a data member of the type 'double'. For the class **Double** I need to overload many basic arithmetic operators like "+", "-", "*", "/". For example, the "+" operator is overloaded this way:

```
Relation<Double>* operator+ (Double &d2)   
// Relation is a abstract class template.
{
   /*
   ...code that do something else.
   */ 
   return new Plus<Double>(this, &d2);   // Plus is derived from Relation.
}                             
// Double + Double returns a Relation pointer.
```

and the "-" operator is overloaded fast the same way:

```
Relation<Double>* operator- (Double &d2)
{
   /*
   ...code that do something else but the same as above.
   */ 
   return new Minus<Double>(this, &d2);
}
```

The actual calculation is done by the member function in the **Relation** class. The only difference of the operators' bodies is the object initialized(**Plus** vs **Minus**).
For operator that takes exactly two operands, I should alway do the overloading like this, which is duplicated and not nice.
So template function comes to my mind. But the problem is, I can pass **Plus** or **Minus** as template argument, but can not pass the operator. How could I make a template or use other methods to do the overloading of these operators?

Comment: It seems that you are parsing some expression. But in that case, why use operator overloading ?

Comment: @liliscent Because I want to enable expressions like this : Double + Double - Double. And then save those relations to class "Relation".

Comment: Not totally clear, but if *do something else* is identical for many operators it looks like it should be delegated to a separate function. The you would have the operator declaration (that you can't do away with), one function call and a return. Looks pretty clean to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, operator overloading may be a pain and source of code duplication, see [this suggestion to the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r3.pdf) to ease it.

For now the only I can think about is something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct OperatorMinus {
  static T doIt(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) { return lhs - rhs; };
}

template<typename T>
struct OperatorPlus {
  static T doIt(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) { return lhs + rhs; };
}

template<typename T, typename U>
class Operator: public Relation<T>
  public:
  Operator(T const& lhs, T const& rhs): _lhs(lhs), _rhs(rhs) {}

  T doIt() override {
    return U::doIt(_lhs, _rhs);
  }

  private:
  T _lhs;
  T _rhs;
};

Relation<Double>* operator+ (Double &d2)   
{
   return new Operator<Double, OperatorPlus<Double>>(this, &d2);
}
```